# redis redis.client rq Queue job.result # => None

Tags: python, redis, python-rq

I'm trying to figure out rq queuing with redis. I have simple test_job function which I want to use in queue.

```
def test_job():
    return "OK"
```

And the script taken mainly from rq documentation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import redis.client
from rq import Queue
import time

from helpers import test_job

def main():

    q = Queue(connection=redis.client.Redis('localhost',6379)) 

    job = q.enqueue(test_job)
    print job.result   # => None

    while not job.result:
        time.sleep(2)
        print job.result   # => None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The problem is that I'm not leaving while loop. job.result remains None. However, redis connection seems to work, according to log:

```
[1279] 30 Dec 12:08:20.041 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 612560 bytes in use
[1279] 30 Dec 12:08:21.371 - Accepted 127.0.0.1:58541
[1279] 30 Dec 12:08:25.337 - DB 0: 23 keys (0 volatile) in 32 slots HT.
[1279] 30 Dec 12:08:25.337 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 633664 bytes in use
```

Comment: As explain before, it only returns 'OK'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you start a worker to process the task?

It looks like no worker is running (as only your client connected to Redis). Run `rqworker` from your project's root.